# Is any UIKit element declared in .h file public or protected in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, public, protected

i am a newbie in iOS development and i have a doubt that if i declare any UIKit element such as UILabel *label in some.h file not in .m file, is it protected or public to other classes if i import this class to another class and access it by using this class instance?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Latestnews_ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *latestnewsbackimg;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *latestnewsdateimg;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latestnewsdate;
```

Is latestnewsdate public or protected??

Comment: You need to provide an example.  There are rules from both C and ObjC that may apply, and without an example, it will be difficult to provide every possibility in an answer.

Comment: Oh, and the data type has no bearing at all on the resulting visibility.

Comment: @Avi please see the code

Answer (score 0):

1).     The Properties in your code can be accessed by any class that is importing your "Latestnews_ViewController". i.e. it is public to all classes.

2).  you can make a private property also in  a class

example:

```
@interface Latestnews_ViewController : UIViewController
{
NSString *latestnewsbackimg;  //private
NSString *latestnewsdateimg;  //private
}

NSArray *array;  //public

@end
```

Comment: What about protected variable??

Comment: interface ClassA : NSObject{
   @ protected
    int _myProtectedInt;
}
end

Answer (score 0):

Properties declared in .h file are `public`. So you can called `latestnewsdate` by instance of `Latestnews_ViewController` from any class. So you can called it public.

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs declaration (interface) and definition (implementation). To use class, you need to see its declaration (to know which methods it have). So, you can type `@interface Foo..` in each file you want to use class `Foo`. But it is pain. That is why you move it to `.h` file and *include* it in another files.

Strictly speaking, there is no difference between .m and .h files for C compiler. .h files are simply included by preprocessor, so compiler may believe you directly include declaration of your class in each file.

So, if you declare something in interface, and include file with this inetrafce to another file, whole interface is accessible, nothing is "protected". There is no such thing as "protected" in ObjC.

What you call "declare any UIKit element" is ObjC *properties*, syntax sugar for field, accessor and mutator (you should read about properties). They are part of interface and not protected. How ever *field* does because it is not part of interface.

To make member "protected" declare it in interface directly in .m file where you implement it. Noone will know about it outside of this file, hense it will be protected.